# Read and write to SQLite database from two different Java applications

Tags: java, sqlite

I have two application. 
One of those should write data to database, and another should read data. 
But "reader" throw exception "database locked".

What ways can be found out of this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems that the database isolation level is set to the serializable, which is the highest one among four. since two applications can access the database simultaneously, the read-only one can read some uncommitted data while write-only one is updating data but not commit yet.

So, if you are sure you want to read data while another one is updating, you can change the isolation level of the database. hope it helps.

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot find example which set isolation level :(

Comment: @christo based on your tag, I assume you are using sqlite, just set PRAGMA read_uncommitted = True; should slove your problem http://www.sqlite.org/sharedcache.html